# Плеер для просмотра SWF файлов

Tags: плеер, swf

Скачал видео уроки, а они в формате SWF, подскажите плеер который может проигрывать SWF с функциями, пазы, перемотки, вперед назад и т.д.

У меня есть какой то, но в нем нет перемотки, очень неудобно.

Плеер нужен для компьютера (ОС: Windows 7)